# One to Many to Many

Tags: database, database-design, filemaker

I have a soccer league project with tables like this....

### --------------------------------------

**LEAGUES TABLE**
League KEY
League Name
Season

---

**TEAMS TABLE**
Team KEY
League KEY
Team Name

---

**PLAYERS TABLE**
Player KEY
Team KEY(s)
Player Name

### --------------------------------------

Each Team can be in one league. Each Player can be assigned to one team in each league. (This is done through the Teams Key(s) compound index field.)

So, a player can be on 3 teams in 3 different leagues. All this works great.

My design is to have each player getting a different jersey number depending on which team you are viewing.

How do I set up a one-to-many-to-many reference like this?

Answer (score 3):

Your title is somewhat misleading, because what you have is a ***many-to-many*** relationship between `Teams` and `Players`: one team has many players, one player can be in many teams.

True, FileMaker does allow you to implement a *many-to-many* relationship by using a *multi-key* field. However, that is a hack that has several limitations - among them the inability to assign any attributes to the individual join of team-to-player, such as the required jersey number.

The proper way to resolve a *many-to-many* relationship is through a *join table* like this:

```
Teams --< TeamPlayers >-- Players
```

where the `TeamPlayers` table would have (at minimum) fields for:

- TeamID (link to Teams)
- PlayerID (link to Players)
- JerseyNumber

and there would be no `Team KEY(s)`field in the `Players` table.

Answer (score -1):

## Many-To-Many

The [Answer by michael.hor257k](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42072447/642706) is correct. You have a [Many-To-Many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relationship between teams and people.

### Relational database

You have outgrown the capabilities of [Filemaker](http://www.filemaker.com). Filemaker is a great product, but it is not a full-fledged relational database. I suggest considering either (a) [4D](http://www.4d.com) or (b) a SQL engine with a front-end like [Xojo](http://www.xojo.com) or [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home).

### Bridge table

A Many-To-Many relationship in relational database design is always resolved by adding a third table, a bridging table. The bridge table always has a pair of foreign keys, linking to each of the many-to-many tables.

The common example of Many-To-Many is books and authors, where a book can have one or more authors and each author can write one or more books. A third table “authorship” must be added. Each row in “authorship” carries the key of a book and a key of an author. If a book has two co-authors, you will find two rows in “authorship” carrying that book’s key value. If an author has written seven books over her career, the “authorship” table will have seven rows carrying that author’s key value.

### Suggested schema

The table design, for the **current info only**, would look like this.

[image]

The `person_` table represents each human being. The `player_` table represents that person’s membership on a team. If Susan plays on three teams, she has three `player_` records, each linking to one of her three teams. She can have a different jersey number on each team, so the `jersey_number_` column belongs to the `player_` table. If `player_` in this context is a term causing confusion in your mind, use `member_` or `membership_` or such for this table bridging `team_` and `person_`.

Issues:

- This structure does not enforce the rule that she can only be on a single team per league.
- This structure is for current membership only.

  - You do not explain the business rules and meaning of `Season` mentioned on `League`.
  - History is not represented here. If you want to track changes over time, such as when Susan joined a particular team and when she quit that team, more needs to be added.

Comment: "*You have outgrown the capabilities of Filemaker. Filemaker is a great product, but it is not a full-fledged relational database.*" Neither statement is correct.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have no desire to re-ignite a flame war about Filemaker not being a relational database. Every tool has its purpose and its limits. You can indeed try to use a hammer as a spanner, but your results are likely to be poor and frustrating.

Comment: I certainly don't intend to argue about facts that can easily be verified.  You are either not using FileMaker, or not using it properly.

Comment: The fact of this project is that the money is coming from the design and implementation of a FileMaker solution. So, I need to use the tools I have.

Comment: @MattRevenaugh Understood. Both my Answer and the Answer of michael.hor257k give you the critical issue: a Many-to-Many between teams and people. I suggest you expand your Question to include discussion of time and the `Season` you mentioned, as that may have further implications for your table design.